# Bank accounts problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given: $4$ bank accounts $A, B, C$ and $D$.

1. First, transfer $\frac 12$ of $A$ into $B$.
2. Next, transfer $\frac 13$ of $B$ into $C$.
3. Next, transfer $\frac 14$ of $C$ into $D$.
4. Next, transfer $\frac 15$ of $D$ into $A$.

Each bank account now has $\$1200$.

How much did each bank account have at the start?

Comment: your own thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

We have $a$, the amount in A to start with, $a^*$ an intermediary value, and $a'$ the amount remaining in A. Similarly for all 4 bank accounts

Consider statement 1:

We will have \begin{align}a^*&=\frac 12 a\\b^*&=b+\frac 12 a\end{align}

Now consider statement 2:

We have \begin{align}b'&=\frac 23 b^*\\&=\frac 23 \left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\\c^*&=c+\frac 13b^*\\&=c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\end{align}

Now consider statement 3:

We have \begin{align}c'&=\frac 34 c^* \\&= \frac 34 \left(c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\right)\\d^*&=d+\frac 14 c^*\\&=d+\frac 14\left(c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\right)\end{align}

Finally consider statement 4:

We have \begin{align}d'&=\frac 45 d^*\\&=\frac 45\left(d+\frac 14\left(c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\right)\right)\\a' &= a^* + \frac 15 d^*\\&=\frac 12 a+ \frac 15\left(d+\frac 14\left(c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\right)\right)\end{align}

To conclude, we now have the following amounts in each account:

\begin{align}a'&=\frac 12 a + \frac 15\left(d+\frac 14\left(c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\right)\right)\\
b'&=\frac 23 \left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\\
c'&=\frac 34 \left(c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\right)\\
d'&=\frac 45\left(d+\frac 14\left(c+\frac 13\left(b+\frac 12 a\right)\right)\right)\end{align}

We can set each of these equal to $\$1200$ and tidy them up:

\begin{align}a'=1200 &= \frac d5+ \frac c{20}+\frac b{60}+\frac {61a}{120}\\
b'=1200&=\frac {2b}3+\frac a3\\
c'=1200&=\frac{3c}4+\frac b4 + \frac a8\\
d'=1200&=\frac {4d}5+\frac c5+\frac b{15}+\frac a{30}
\end{align}

We can solve these simultaneous equations, I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201200%20%3D%20d%2F5%2Bc%2F20%2Bb%2F60%2B61a%2F120,%201200%3D2b%2F3%2Ba%2F3,%201200%3D3c%2F4%2Bb%2F4%2Ba%2F8,%201200%3D4d%2F5%2Bc%2F5%2Bb%2F15%2Ba%2F30%20for%20a,b,c,d) for speed, but you can do them by hand, and we obtain the results:

\begin{align}a&=\$1800\\
b&=\$900\\
c&=\$1000\\
d&=\$1100\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We have the following equations to solve:

(1)     B + A/2  =  W

(2)     C + W/3  =  X

(3)     D + X/4  =  Y

(4)     A/2 + Y/5  =  Z

(5)     (2/3) * (W)  =  1200

(6)     (3/4) * (X)  =  1200

(7)     (4/5) * (Y)  =  1200

(8)     Z  = 1200

Solving equations (5) thru (8) yield:

W = 1800

X = 1600

Y = 1500

Z = 1200

Solving equations (1) thru (4) yield:     [Solve equation (1) last.]

A = 1800

B = 900

C = 1000

D = 1100

Notes:

i.)   At the start:  total of 4 bank accounts  =  A + B + C + D  =  1800 + 900 + 1000 + 1100  =  4800

ii.)  After all transfers:  total of 4 bank accounts  =  1200 + 1200 + 1200 + 1200  =  4800

Answer:  A = $1800, B = $900, C = $1000, D = $1100

Comment: Why do you ask a question and $8$ minutes later you write an answer?

Comment: @Arnaldo I agree, at least if you've finally solved a question, then take the time to format the answer so it is easily followed